# Difference in ability to use contravariance when using a Func<T> parameter

Tags: c#, contravariance

I am curious as to why the following logic is allowed in C#

```
private static void Foo(Func<Exception, string> func)
{
    try
    {
        // ...  
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        func(ex);
    }
}
```

whereas this is not

```
private static void Foo<T>(Func<T, string> func) where T : Exception
{
    try
    {
        // ...  
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        func(ex);
    }
}
```

From what I understand, since the `Func<in TArg1, out TResult>` delegate has a contravariant parameter since .NET 4.0, the first scenario is not problem, but why does switching to a **constrained** generic type change the ability of the compiler to apply this contravariance ?

Comment: What if `T` is `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: You're not switching to a **constrained** generic type; you're switching to a constrained **generic** type, if you take my meaning. Your first method is not generic. You can always pass any subclass of `Exception` to a func which wants an `Exception`. You can't pass any subclass of `Exception` to a func which wants a specific subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: Well said. You first example was straight to the point. Don't hesitate to post an answer that's along these lines.

Comment: I think that I was concentrating on the fact that the only thing we know about `T` is that it's an `Exception`, which led me to believe that the `Func ` could take any exception type. I ignored the fact that I was imposing a concrete, specific constraint on what type was allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first function will compile, however due to contravariance of `Func` parameters, you can only pass a `Func` with a parameter which is a supertype of `Exception` e.g.

```
Func<object, string> f = o => o.ToString();
Foo(f);
```

this is not the case in the second example, which would require you to pass a `Func` with a parameter which is a subtype of `Exception` e.g

```
Func<InvalidOperationException> f = o => ...
```

which would not be safe.